# how to handle laravel login errors, username different from password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, laravel-5.4

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I want to handle failed login errors message. But I want make it a little more custom. I want to show special errors like (username not found) or (password is wrong).

What can I do? (I did it and it's working, check my new failed login method, is this correct and standard?)

Failed login method:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
    ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
    ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

in my blade:

```
@if ($errors->first('phone'))
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

my new failed method:

```
if (!User::where('phone', $request->phone)->first()){
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => 'user not found',
        ]);
}


if (!User::where('phone', $request->phone)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first()){
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            'password' => 'password is incorrect',
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the default auth validation messages in your resources > lang > en > passwords.php or auth.php files

Comment: but my only error message is : auth.failed and its not in resources

Comment: I would recommend you to overwrite your own authcontroller postlogin function and create your own custom validation to handle the returning of login errors to the view instead of sending the errors yourself. Laravel has a guide for that here for custom validation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: as far as i know, this is the cleanest, and it makes full use of what laravel has offered

Comment: i did it , check my update. is that standard and fine??

Comment: Did you run php artisan make:auth?